# Run a command every time a change in keyboard hardware is detected

Tags: keyboard, xorg, shortcut-keys, automation, xmodmap

I use a custom keyboard layout [Ubuntu Desktop 16.04 with Unity], via `xkb` and `Xmodmap` (similar to https://superuser.com/a/111968/488410).

However, each time I restart the machine, dock/undock, plug/unplug a keyboard, or (most commonly) insert/remove a YubiKey (which registers itself as a USB keyboard), my custom keybindings fall away.

Currently I have a short bash alias for `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap`, which I run from a terminal when this happens (5-20 times a day!). However, I'd like it to happen automatically.

- How can I tell when Ubuntu has detected a change in keyboard hardware?
- How can I configure it to run a bash script each time a change is detected?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to solve this with udev rules that are invoked when your keyboard is plugged in.  Not sure if it will help if your keyboard is messed up when something else is plugged in.